# Is there a way to get a variable by a given string

Tags: javascript, variables

You have a variable:

```
const test = "Some random value."
```

and the name of the variable in a **string** format:

```
const input = "test"
```

is there a way to get the value **without a enum**?

```
console.log(someMagicFunction(input))
```

*$ => "Some random value."*

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that is possible, but what is the objective to do this i.e `to get the value of a constant without its reference.`?

Comment: By enum, do you mean an Object? If so I am afraid it is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer - no.

You are kind of describing the behavior of a [pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)) - sort of... You want to get what is stored in memory and referenced as the variable `test`. JS does not support that.

There are things you could do such as store the keys and values in a hash map (an object) and have a similar effect.

```
const store = {
    test: "Some random value.",
    foo: "bar"
};

const magicHappensHere = (key) => {
    return store[key];
};

console.log(magicHappensHere('test')); // "Some random value."
```